# Using Almond with inline requireJs

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, almond

Here is my grunt file part where I define the requirejs task:

```
    requirejs: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                name: 'almond',
                mainConfigFile: "<%= yeoman.app %>/js/main.js",
                out: '.tmp/require/js/app.js',
                insertRequire: ['startup'],
                optimize: 'none'
            }
        }
    }
```

Now in my andular application I mainly load vendor sources that I downloaded through bower.

However I have this need to load the amplitude.com module and it does not seem to have a bower link.

So here is my code:

```
define(['application/amplitude/module', 'require'], function (module, require) {
    'use strict';

    module.provider('$amplitude', [function $amplitudeProvider() {
        this.$get = ['$q', function ($q) {
            var sync = $q.defer();

            requirejs.config({
                paths: {
                    'amplitude': 'https://d24n15hnbwhuhn.cloudfront.net/libs/amplitude-3.4.1-min.gz'
                },
                shim: {
                    'amplitude': {
                        exports: 'amplitude'
                    }
                }
            });
            require(['amplitude'], function (amplitude) {
                sync.resolve(amplitude);
            });
            return {
                getInstance: function() { return sync.promise; }
            }; 
        }];
    }]);
});
```

It works like a charm in dev mode.
Now when I try to grunt release (which runs the almond task) the thats succeeds but I get an error at runtime saying

> Uncaught Error: undefined missing

I tried different ways of writing that but all failed... Anyone able to show the light?

Comment: Almond does not allow loading external URLs. Nothing dynamic. Everything must be already present in the bundle you give to Almond. If you want to load dynamically, you can switch to RequireJS.